# What kind of web page is this?

Tags: website-design, terminology, website-templates

[image: sample]

What do you call this page? I know it's a login page but what type of page is this?

Would you call it a "single page template", different from the other pages in a template, and easy to insert some external content?

The best examples that I know are "forgot password" pages and "login" pages.

Comment: Could possibly be a modal window.

Comment: There are too many words that this image fits in. Do you have other examples of the same thing you're looking for so that we can see what is in common between several of them?

Answer (score 2):

A **Single Page Template**, as name states, is a page with all elements within one page - even if you click on item on navigation menu, it just scrolls down to an anchor point on said page.

It creates more captivating interactions and make browsing your site a linear experience - you decide in what order your content should be read. In multi page template, it's the user that decides what subpage to enter next.

As to a page example you've send - it's a login page, login screen, fullscreen login form. There is no precise term for those things, I mean, there is no term say "aardvark" that will mean a fullscreen login page - it's much more contextual and fluid. There are some widely popular terms, like *hamburger menu* or *hero image* that references a popular website elements, but usually it's all really content and context based.

The process of designing pages, designing interactions and preparing a schematic of what you want to show on your website is actually called wireframing. Planning what you want to achieve and how to show it, should be one of first steps in your creative process. There are many tools and articles online how to get started with this, I'll link you some - you might want to read a thing or two about modern app development in general as the process of creating a website is not much unlike developing a typical app.

http://www.awwwards.com/wireframe-basics-for-beginners-an-agency-perspective.html
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-wireframing--webdesign-7399